# CI url formating not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

i am currently working with CI. I need some help with removing index.php from url.
I tried a lot and could  not figure out my issue. I checked solution but was not helpful.

My .htaccess file ->

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

also changed

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to:

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

and made `$config['base_url']     = 'my working url';`

can anyone help ???

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this .htaccess :

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it is not working.. :(
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/test/testfn -> working
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/test/testfn -> 404 error

Comment: You are on Windows (in local) ? Or on your webserver ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu(local)

Comment: Ok on ubuntu try the same code but delete the row : "RewriteBase /". I took a look on my Code Igniter .htaccess on my Debian server, and it works.

Comment: Hi Vincet, it also didn't work. Can't figure out whats the issue. Stuck with the issue.. :-(